# About Spliting Field

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

What is splitting field of polynomial $X^3+X+\bar 1$ in $\mathbb{F_5}$.
Attempt: To show this we first want to check irreducibility which is clear in case of finite field since there are only 5 elements so put values and check it has no root in $\mathbb{F_5}$. After that how to proceed?

Comment: The splitting field contains all roots of the polynomial. If $a$ is a root, then check how the polynomial decomposes in ${\Bbb F}_5(a)$.

Comment: So say a is root then $a^3+a+1=0$ so what can I do after that?

Comment: Divide the polynomial into $x-a$.

Comment: Can you please tell me how?

Comment: @Wuestenfux I know if we quotient out it with irreducible then we get field with 125 elements but then how to show polynomial completely splits over there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your polynomial is an irreducible cubic over the finite field $\Bbb F_5$. Adjoining one root gives you a field with $5^3$ elements. It’s not hard to see that any extension of finite fields is (automatically) normal. So you may say that the splitting field is $\Bbb F_{125}$.

Knowing a little more about finite fields, you can determine that, with $f(X)=X^3+X+1$ and $a$ your constructed root of $f$ in $\Bbb F_{125}$, you get $a^5=4a^2+a+1$ and $a^{25}=a^2+3a+4$, and $f(X)=(X-a)(X-a^5)(X-a^{25})$

Comment: Is it obvious that $f(X)=(X-a)(X-a^5)(X-a^{25})$ ? Or even that the other roots are $4a^2+a+1$ and $a^2+3a+4$ ?

Comment: Well, @lhf, we know that if $a$ is a root of $f(X)\in\Bbb F_q[X]$, then $a^q$ is also a root. Because $z\mapsto z^q$ is an $\Bbb F_q$-automorphism of any algebraic extension of $\Bbb F_q$. In this case, $q=5$ and our field is cubic, so $a$, $a^5$, and $a^{25}$ are the only conjugates of $a$. It’s certainly *not* obvious that the conjugates of $a$ have the form they turned out to have: that required a computation.

Answer (score 1):

My answer to this question with software is in the following form.

First, I find a positive integer $n$ such that in the decomposition of $x^n-1$ in modulo $5$  we have the factor $x^3+x+1$. In your question we get $n=62$. In fact, we get 
$$
(x^{62}-1) \pmod{5}=
\left( {x}^{3}+2\,x+4 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}+2\,x+1 \right)  \left( 
{x}^{3}+{x}^{2}+3\,x+4 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}+4\,{x}^{2}+x+1 \right) 
 \left( x+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}+3\,{x}^{2}+4 \right)  \left( {x}^{
3}+{x}^{2}+3\,x+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}+2\,{x}^{2}+x+4 \right) 
 \left( {x}^{3}+{x}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}+3\,{x}^{2}+4\,x+1
 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}+x+4 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}+4\,{x}^{2}+3\,x+4
 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}+3\,{x}^{2}+x+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}+x+1
 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}+{x}^{2}+4\,x+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}+4\,{x}
^{2}+4 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}+{x}^{2}+x+4 \right)  \left( x+4
 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}+4\,{x}^{2}+3\,x+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}+2\,
{x}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{3}+2\,{x}^{2}+4\,x+4 \right)  \left( {x
}^{3}+4\,{x}^{2}+4\,x+4 \right) 
$$
Then, we obtain a positive integer $k$ such that $62\mid 5^k-1$ which is $k=3$. Then, we construct $\mathbb{F}_{5^3}$ with any irreducible polynomial such as $\bf f$.

Finally, we choose  elements of the field $\mathbb{F}_{5^3}$ that their order is $62$ and test which of these elements satisfy $x^3+x+1=0$.